# How to pass already-fetched data to a controller when it's expecting a promise

Tags: angularjs

I have a service in Angular that fetches a list of querys from a database table.  The user selects one and moves on to another view to work with it.  When the user clicks back to the first view though, I'd like to avoid re-fetching the query list.  The query list is stored in the service but I'm having a hard time handing it back to the controller given that my fetch routine uses .then and promises.

```
app.service('queryService', function ($http) 
{
  var querys        = new Object();

  this.loadQueryList = function() 
  {
    if (querys!=null)
    {
      //how to return the querys list here?  caller expecting a promise
    }   

    var promise = $http.post("php/datapump.php", { action: "FETCH", item: "QUERYS", id1: null, id2: null})
      .then(function (response) 
      {
         querys=response.data;
         return querys;
      });
    return promise; // Return the promise to the controller
  };
});
```

In the controller initialization the service is called with:

```
queryService.loadQueryList().then(function(d) 
{
  $scope.querys = d;
  $scope.selectedquery=queryService.getSelectedQuery();
});
```

Or is there a better method altogether?  I can imagine setting some flag in the service to get around this but it seems ugly.  I simply want to avoid fetching the data a 2nd time.

Comment: There's a couple of methods to handle "sharing" data between services and controllers, namely angular.copy and a watch come to mind aside from what you're doing here with promises.  If you stick with promises you can just return the promise in the case that query is not null but immediately call resolve on the promise, as is you're not showing where the promise is resolved or rejected though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create your own promise and resolve it immediately. This is much nicer than setting a flag and returning some cached data directly because it keeps your service interface consistent - that method always returns a promise.

```
 var deferred = $q.defer();
 deferred.resolve(yourdata);
 return deferred.promise;
```

You will obviously need to inject $q into your service.

Comment: Thank you, that's just what I needed.  For the second part of the question: is there a better way?  I'd like to use the $http service, and I'd like to avoid fetching data twice, is this the best way?

Comment: I think it is a good approach - I have used it on a recent project. Angular gives you two main ways to interact with HTTP servers - $http, which is configurable but requires a certain amount of boilerplate, and Resources, which make some assumptions about your server-side API but, for simple CRUD operations, allow for cleaner code. Given that you need a certain level of control over how and when Angular makes HTTP requests, $http is the right choice for you.